# Endofunctors of $\mathbf{Set}$ that don't preserve monomorphisms

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples

Every functor $\mathbf{Set} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ I can think of preserves monomorphisms (i.e. injective functions), including:

- $\mathrm{Hom}(X,-)$,
- $X \times -$,
- $X \sqcup -$,
- and the constant functors.

The monads I can think of all have this property, too.

What are some natural examples that don't?

Comment: I just found out that in my answer I told you something that you allready knew. See the comment on [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/642341/75923).

Comment: @drhab, the tables have turned!

Comment: Of course without the "natural" part there are many answers (e.g. if $F$ is the functor defined on objects by $F(S) = \{1\}$ if $S \neq \emptyset$ and $F(\emptyset) = \{1,2\}$ and on morphisms in the only way possible).

Comment: I would have thought any such functor would have to be pretty unnatural, as in @Nex’s example. Interested to see if anyone comes up with a natural example!

Comment: Actually, maybe @Nex’s example is more natural than it looks. Isn’t it the same as  $\mathrm{Hom}(Hom(-,\varnothing),2)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a real answer on your question, but it might be enlightening.

Every functor preserves sections (i.e. split monomorphims) and in **Set** almost all monomorphisms are sections.

The only exceptions are the functions $\varnothing\to Y$ where $Y\neq\varnothing$.

These are the only functions that are monic, but do not have a left-inverse.

So it is not so strange that endofunctors in **Set** that do not preserve monomorphisms are hard to find.

In order to find a counterexample (or maybe a proof that all monomorphisms are preserved by endofunctors in **Set**) you will have to focus on the mentioned functions.

Comment: Your answer implies that one only needs to check if $\emptyset \to \{*\}$ is preserved (since any function $\emptyset \to Y$ where $Y \neq \emptyset$ factors as $\emptyset \to \{*\}\to S$).

Comment: @Nex Yes, you are right. Nice observation.