# Functors on $\mathbf{Set}$ preserve epics and monics

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I'm trying to prove that a functor $F:\mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Set}$ preserves epics and monics, but I'm stuck more or less at the beginning of the proof.

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is epic. Consider $F(f):F(X)\to F(Y)$. To show that it's epic, I assume we need to use the characterization of epics in the category of sets (i.e. that epics=surjective maps) - how else can we take advantage of working with sets? So, assume $\beta\in F(Y)$. Need to find $\alpha\in F(X)$ with $F(f)(\alpha)=\beta$. To use the surjectivity of $f$, we need to get hold of an element of $Y$. But I don't see any way to get an element of $Y$ from an element of $F(Y)$ for an arbitrary functor $F$.

With injectivity, we have the same problem. Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is monic (=injective). Suppose $F(f)(\alpha_1)=F(f)(\alpha_2)$. Again, to use the definition of injectivity of $f$, we need (I suppose) an element of $Y$ that is equal to $f(something_1)$ and also to $f(something_2)$.

I've also tried thinking in terms of cancellation of arrows in both cases, but it doesn't seem to be beneficial, and in that case I don't know how to take advantage of the category of sets.

Comment: Well, one difficulty with proving this is that it is not true.  For instance, $F$ could send the empty set to a $2$-element set and every other set to a singleton.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oops, for injectivity I guess the statement should be that the image of any injective function from a nonempty set is monic.

Comment: @EricWofsey Is it right that any function $\emptyset\to S$, where $S$ is nonempty, is empty, and its image under $F$ must be a function $\{1,2\}\to \{3\}$; there is only one such function, and it is not injective?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @EricWofsey Does a similar argument prove that there exists no functor that would map some nonempty set to the empty set and some other nonempty set to a nonempty set? I think if $F$ maps a nonempty $S$ to the empty set and if $T$ is nonempty, then there are many maps $S\to T$ (at least, more than one, unless $S$ and $T$ are both singletons, in which my proof doesn't seem to work). But there is only one map $\emptyset=FS\to FT$ (the empty map). So $FT$ must be empty too (at least if $S$ and $T$ are not both singletons).

Comment: No, that argument is not correct.  A functor can send multiple different maps to the same map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the axiom of choice, you can prove that epimorphisms (surjections) split in $\mathbf{Set}$, meaning that if $f \colon A \to B$ is epic, then there exists $g \colon B \to A$ such that $f \circ g = \text{id}_B$. From there, you just need to prove that functors preserve split epimorphisms.

The corresponding statement for monomorphisms isn't true (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1893960/199074)). However, monomorphisms with non-empty domain split, so the same proof would work for those.

Comment: Is the fact that surjections split immediate from the axiom of choice? You just take (in each set $f^{-1}(b)$ where $b$ ranges over $B$) an element that the axiom of choice gives and this defines $g$. Or am I missing something? And the fact that functors preserve split epimorphisms seems to be obvious too.

Comment: @user634426 I think you've got it.

Comment: And if $f$ is monic, then $g$ is defined by sending every $b\in B$ that has a preimage to the unique $a\in A$ such that $a\mapsto b$, and any $b\in B$ that doesn't have a preimage to any element of $A$? If $A$ is empty and $B$ is not, then the reason why $f$ does not split is that there are no functions $B\to A$ at all?

Comment: @user634426 Yep